# pixie debugger in Jupyter showing weird characters

Tags: jupyter, pixiedust

Installs okay and runs with the slick buttons and everything, but

```
%%pixie_debugger

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

starter = np.zeros( (10,10))
```

Looks like :

```
[0m[1;32mdef[0m [0mpixie_run[0m[1;33m([0m[1;33m)[0m[1;33m:[0m[1;33m[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m    [1;32mimport[0m [0mpdb[0m[1;33m[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m    [0mpdb[0m[1;33m.[0m[0mset_trace[0m[1;33m([0m[1;33m)[0m[1;33m[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[1;33m    [1;32mimport[0m [0mpandas[0m [1;32mas[0m [0mpd[0m[1;33m[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m    [1;32mimport[0m [0mnumpy[0m [1;32mas[0m [0mnp[0m[1;33m[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m    [0mstarter[0m [1;33m=[0m [0mnp[0m[1;33m.[0m[0mzeros[0m[1;33m([0m [1;33m([0m[1;36m10[0m[1;33m,[0m[1;36m10[0m[1;33m)[0m[1;33m)[0m[1;33m[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
[0m[1;33m[0m[0m
```

Comment: Did you end up working out what was causing this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I gave up and was able to make do with %debug. Pixie has a slick UI, but needs work to be dependable..

Comment: I have same problem and not able to solve it.